# Expected number of rolls that land on side $6

Tags: probability

Suppose the die is rolled until $1$ or $2$ is observed on $5$ rolls. Determine the expected number of rolls that land on side $6$.
I don't understand why it is $5\times\left(\dfrac 12\right)$.

Please explain. Thank you.

Comment: What do you think it should be?

Comment: I  think i just got it. Since E(X) of land on 6 side is 1/2, then just 1/2 multiply by 5. @MatthewLeingang

Comment: I agree with you.  The degree to which you will have to prove each of those statements depends on your situation.

Answer (score 2):

The probability distribution of the number of die rolls until five 1s or 2s are observed is [negative binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution) with parameters $r=5$ and $p=\frac{2}{3}$ ($\frac{2}{3}$ is the probability of *not* observing a 1 or 2 on any roll), so the expected total number of rolls is $$\frac{r}{1-p}=\frac{5}{1-\frac{2}{3}} = 15.$$ One sixth of these rolls are expected to be 6s, so the number of 6s is expected to be $$15\cdot\frac{1}{6}=5\cdot\frac{1}{2}.$$